# Translation of a compact set in $\mathbb R^n$ and continuous affine maps

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, continuity, convex-analysis, linear-transformations

Suppose $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ is  compact. Suppose for $a\in \mathbb R^n, a\neq 0$

$$Y=\{ x+a|  x\in X\}$$

Can I conclude that $Y$ is also compact?

Furthermore,  would it be true that any affine transformation for a set in  $\mathbb R^n$ is continuous?

Thanks.

Comment: In fact, for any $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$  the map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself given by $x\mapsto x+a$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every affine map from $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is continous.

**Proof:** Note that every affine map can be written as a composite of a linear map and a translation. Since any [linear map between finite dimensional normed spaces is continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#A_linear_map_from_a_finite-dimensional_space_is_always_continuous) and the composite of continuous maps is continuous, it follows that we need only show that a translation is continuous. Suppose $f(x)=x+a$ for some $a$. Since for an open ball $B(c,r)$ , $f^{-1}(B(c,r))=B(c-a,r)$ is an open ball it follows that $f$ is continous.

This answers both your first and second question since the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: Hi, the answer is very hold helpful. I have another question, is the conclusion also hold for infinite dimensional spaces? for example, the class of $L_p$ spaces or more general spaces?

Comment: No. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#General_existence_theorem